# Are all of the default scripts loaded by Magento really needed?

Tags: magento, prototypejs, javascript

Here's a listing of all the scripts loaded by Magento by default:

```
../js/prototype/prototype.js    //prototype library
../js/prototype/validation.js   //don't know what this does
../js/scriptaculous/builder.js  //don't know what this does
../js/scriptaculous/effects.js  //base scriptaculous effects library?
../js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js //component of scriptaculous effects
../js/scriptaculous/controls.js //not sure?
../js/scriptaculous/slider.js   //more scriptaculous effects
../js/varien/js.js          //don't know what this is
../js/varien/form.js        //form validation scripts?
../js/varien/menu.js        //menu/drop down menu scripts
../js/mage/translate.js     //don't know what this does
../js/mage/cookies.js       //don't know what this does
```

these scripts total 316.8K of javascript... all in various states of being minified (for example, prototype.js isn't minified).

So my first question:

1) Aside from prototype.js, are all of the others really that needed?

and

2) What is the "correct" way to remove these scripts?  Layout updates?  Or hardcoded in templates?

I want to make the loading of my magento site as light weight as possible.

thanks!

Comment: Magento: Pro, Elegant & Lightweight extension! Brought to you by JoomlArt.com. You want to make it even more Leightweight? :)

Comment: As a trivial optimization, minify prototype.js :)

Comment: I was wondering the same, I'm trying to speed up my site. I just enabled gzip and my javascript file sizes reduced by 70%.

Comment: @Joseph Mastey.  I think you're being facetious, but yes... prototype doesn't like being minified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***To answer Part 1*** - no not all of these are required, but most are and it depends on your theme.
A default magento theme uses them all, but a custom one almost certainly won't need all the scriptaculous ones.

The varien, mage and prototype ones will almost always be required, creating a theme that does away with all of these is very, very, hard because some of the in page javascript that depends on them actually comes not from the theme but from the core php files.

On simple themes I've had good results removing dragdrop and slider as I don't use the product zoom display. You can remove menu if you're not using the Magento menu, but only if you're prepared to make dummy js functions to catch any calls to it left behind - the menu navigation object injects javascript function directly from the php layer that need to be caught (or better yet you can roll your own category navigation object that doesn't do this!).

***For Part 2*** - edit your themes page.xml layout to remove them from the 
    `<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">`
tag. I suggest commenting them out and testing each one as you go.

You can inject required javascript files into the page types that do need them by adding javascript tags to the head section of the appropriate layout files. As an example of how this is done have a look at the default sendfriend.xml layout file which adds the product.js file to the head only for pages that need it.

If you start adding/removing javascript aggressively based on page type you also need to consider how Magento merges javascript files. There's a setting in the developer area of the configuration screens to merge javascript files, turning this on is a very good thing. 
This merges all javascript files inside the head area that have been injected using the "addJs" or "addItem" with an item type of "js" or "skin_js".

BUT because of this if you start including/excluding scripts on a page by page basis you'll find that you're generating different merged js files on different pages - destroying most of the benefits of caching a single large js file!

To get the best of both worlds you should be able to inject js into the head using  but without specifying the item type, thus preventing that file from being merged - but I've not tried this yet. If this works you'll find the core libraries merged and your per page custom files included individually, meaning you cache the big one and they only download the bit that changes.

Answer (score 1):

I cant say what they are all for but I know that most of them are needed annoyingly as Magento does use allot of JS.

This does not answer your question but you can minimise their effect with Magento 1.4.01 (probably in 1.4.0 as well) by going into System -> Config -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript settings and then merge them all so you only have one HTTP request (same can be done with CSS).

I would guess that the "most correct" way to go about removing them would be to make a new theme that does not need them and not include them as they would not be needed so in answer to question 2 i would say templates would most definitely be the way forward. I cannot remember the exact template that controls this but I'm sure I have seen one that has a big list of JS / CSS includes

Comment: JS is often defined inside of the page.xml (or other layout.xml) files. +1 on those files being generally necessary to operate the site, though not every script is used on every page.

Comment: @Joseph Mastey - ya, though they aren't needed on every page, I just find it such a huge waste to include 3 different UI libraries just to do a menu dropdown.

Comment: merging JS files masks the problem, but I'm interested in solving the problem.  I'm fine with using prototype, so this isn't a "how do i use jquery with magento" post.  And i'm fine with creating layout updates per page to include only the js needed.  I just don't like including resources that are only minimally used.

Comment: Well if you went through your install and cleaned up all of the css/js includes into one of the header files and then included them optionally using a switch based on the body class of the page (a different class is applied to each page depending on its id or something of the like) you would then only get the required files on each page ... admitedley this is a bit of a work around but it offers an approach to what you are trying to do

- Merging the JS files will speed page loads as it will cut down on the no of http requests made .. although i doubt this will work with the above solution.

Comment: @Chris Hopkins.  Your suggestions are exactly what I'm looking to do, I just want to know what the different scripts are, and their purpose... so that I can make sure I'm not breaking anything magento needs while removing scripts.  And yes, merging all the JS files will pages load faster by eliminating the http requests and downloads... but the browser will still need to process the js.  And that would be what I'm trying to reduce, the amount of work a browser has to invest in running through these scripts on every page.

Comment: Conditionally importing the JS is not a great savings though. Although an empty cache hit for the page is really nonoptimal under this arrangement, you should have caching headers set for the files, in which case the browser will not need to request the files again. And w/ conditionals + the merging, you'll actually have worse cache performance.